# get some word from return String - rest function

Tags: json, node.js, rest, buffer

In that case I've already tried to get the returned JSON, but when I use the JSON.parse and the JSON.stringify it returns undefined. If I do not use and leave only the  `data = data.toString('utf8');`, return:

```
!!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rest.schema.CtLoginResp {error: null, sessionID: 6dMX4uGVurFdLRL+hW4F2kIW}
```

And I want the sessionid... But If i try get this, return undefined, I try JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, see that:

**My code:**

```
var Client = require('./lib/node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();

var dataLogin = {
   data: { "userName":"xxxxxxxxxxx","password":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","platform":"xxxxxxx" },
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
};

client.registerMethod("postMethod", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/login", "POST");

client.methods.postMethod(dataLogin, function (data, response) {
   // parsed response body as js object
   // console.log(data);
   // raw response
if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){ // if i remove buffer return is 21 22 etc etc 
   data = data.toString('utf8'); // this return all but String
    var outputTe = data;
    var res = outputTe.split(" ", 4);
        res = res[3].split("}", 1);
  }
console.log(res);
});
```

**Image return:**

In the case if i does not use Buffer return is 21 34 56 etc. 
But if I use return is all the **STRING** `data.toString();` inside the image...

[image]

**EDIT.**

I try use `split` but return just the string "sessionid" see the other image:

[image]

**I try same code inside W3 schools and does not work inside my code but in W3 school test works fine:**

**1)**
[image]

**2)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In the case I use regex:**

```
client.methods.postMethod(dataLogin, function (data, response) {

    if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
      data = data.toString('utf8');
      console.log(data);
      var re = /(sessionID: )([^,}]*)/g;
      var match = re.exec(data);
      var sessionid = match[2]
      console.log(sessionid);
      openRequest(numberOrigin); 
      }
    });
```